# Как записывать интервал дат?

Tags: тире, даты

Дата такого плана: *15 марта – 28 апреля.* Тире с пробелами? Верно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, всё верно. Без пробелов нельзя хотя бы потому, что части (число и месяц) состоят не из одного слова, дефис нельзя рассматривать и по этой же причине, и потому, что интервал разделяется именно тире.